# Error Converting Java Object to JSON Object

Tags: java, json

Using jackson API, I am trying to convert java object to json string. I have gone through several posts but not able to through the below stack-trace.

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No serializer found for class java.io.FileDescriptor and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: com.imc.idm.data.request.DirectoryDetailData["logoImage"]->org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile["inputStream"]->java.io.FileInputStream["fd"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:284)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.mappingException(SerializerProvider.java:1110)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.reportMappingProblem(SerializerProvider.java:1135)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.failForEmpty(UnknownSerializer.java:69)
```

My code is similar to this one below:

```
public class Infomation {
    private MultipartFile img;
    private Manufacture manufacture;
    private List<Long> otherVal1;
    private List<MyCustomClass> otherVal2;
}
```

Component :

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
final String jsonString = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(infomationObject);
final MyDTO myDto = MyDTO.newBuilder().withValue(jsonString).build();
dataRepository.save(myDto);
```

Comment: make sure your classes are serializable, i mean they implements Serializable interface.

Comment: Do I need to serialize Infomation class only, because MultipartFile is the class present in apis.

Comment: What is `objectMapper` and what is `infomationObject`. Please provide more information

Comment: infomationObject is the object of Information class, which I am getting when do Post call.

Answer (score 1):

Serializable interface/marker is  not implemented in **MultipartFile**.

If you have **Spring Web** in your dependencies, you can use **CommonsMultipartFile** as it implements Serializable and MultipartFile.

For more information, please see [Commons Multipart File Java API](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/4.3.5.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/commons/CommonsMultipartFile.html)